# Passing parameter between community pages

Tags: lightning-aura-components, community-builder

I have created two pages using community builder (register and registerdetail)
Now, i need to pass values from page1(register) to page2(registerdetail).
i tried lightning event to communicate between these two pages which includes lightning component.

please help me with suggestions.

Page1 Register - Registercomponent

Page2 RegisterDetail - RegisterDetailComponent

Thanks
Bala

Answer (score 1):

You can put a value in the url to redirect to the second page. So in the second page you can get the values in the url. 
If you use a constructor you can use
 `Apex.currentPage().getParameter ('paramName')`.
 Otherwise if you have only the page you can use javascript.

Comment: Yes,that will work, But i dont want to pass the information over URL.

Comment: You can use method post inside get. Or also the tag <apex:function>

Comment: i have to send username and password between these two pages, so i'm thinking of something more secured.

Comment: I think passing parameters with post method over https protocol is secured enough.

Comment: I'm using lightning component, so it would be great if you explain in detail.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the Hash Params in the URL someting like this
"https://yourdomain.force.com/community/s/yourpage#param1:param1value"
In javascript you can get the hash value like this

```
var param1 = location.hash;
```

now parse the whole thing to split by `:` and try to get the param value you wanted to pass. Maybe this will work